# Using Automator to combine URL with text variable on clipboard

Tags: bash, shell, automator

I have a URL and I need a script to combine a variable to the end. The variable is on the clipboard.

First I need to run sed to clean up the variable so it's just numbers:

```
sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'
```

Then store the variable and append it to the end of a specific URL.

Then open that URL.

I looked around. Maybe I could use awk?

Comment: Given the apple only tool,t his Q may be more appropriate on the related site http://apple.stackexchange.com (AskDifferently). Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it there. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have whatever you want already in the clipboard (*pasteboard*):

```
$ open "http://example.com?$(pbpaste | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')"
```

Comment: That's it!. Thank you. For some reason the sed argument is not working properly now. The copied text still has dashes.

Comment: Try `pbpaste | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'` alone to see if the results match your expectation

Comment: The sed argument was fine. The website is re-formating the URL.